# Textbox should allow only Hexa decimal values

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox and i can enter only 2 digits. What i want is that user can only input Hexa values in it like 12,a0,0a (2 digits) if user enters any ather value , it will not be entered. Can you please help.

```
<input onkeyup=validateHexa(this); class='nbb' maxlength='2'  value='??'/>

function validateHexa(ele){
var control = ele.value;
var regExp = new RegExp(/^([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}){8,9}$/);
if (!regExp.test(control))
 ele.value="true";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```js
function replaceInput(ele) {
  var re = /[^A-Fa-f0-9]/g;
  ele.value = ele.value.replace(re, '');
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup=replaceInput(this); class='nbb' maxlength='2'  placeholder='??' pattern="[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}"/>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwscbyvr/)**

Comment: Hi, 
Not able to do.. can you please create a JSFiddle link for me

Comment: @AbhinavParashar Added a link to a JSFiddle above.

Answer (score 0):

hello there you should try Regular expression like `([aA-hH 0-9]{2})`
please comment if any issue :)